# Is $z^2-i(x^2-y^2)$ analytic in $\mathbb{D}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Is $f(z)=z^2-i(x^2-y^2)$ analytic in $\mathbb{D}$?

I think it is because it is complex differentiable at $\mathbb{D}$. In other words it has unique complex derivative at all points of $\mathbb{D}$. 
But how do you get complex derivative, because $f(z)$ seems to be other than function of $z$? 
Unless there is a theorem that says that if $f$ satisfies C-R equations then $f$ is analytic. But now $f$ does not satisfy C-R equations.

Comment: What are $x$ and $y$ ?

Comment: Do you mean $\,z=x+iy\,,\,\,\,x,y\in\Bbb R\,$ ?

Comment: $z^2$ is analytic, so if $f$ is, then so is $x^2-y^2$. Is it?

Comment: DonAntonio: Yes I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I f you meant $\,z=x+iy\,,\,\,x,y\in\Bbb R\,$ , then

$$z^2-i(x^2-y^2)=x^2-y^2+(2xy+x^2-y^2)i = u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$$

$$u_x=2x\neq 2x-2y=v_y$$

and thus the Cauchy-Riemann conditions aren't fulfilled...

Comment: It seems that you mean that because C-R-equations aren't fulfilled, then it is not analytic in $\mathbb{D}$? I mean that necessary condition for $f$ to be analytic in $\mathbb{D}$ is that C-R-equations are satisfied?

Comment: Yup. The condition is a necessary one, and adding (real) differentiabiality and continuity of the first derivatives they also are sufficient.

Comment: According to my knowledge, if C-R-equations are satisfied for $u$ and $v$ and first partial derivative of $u$ and $v$ exists and they are also continuous, then $f$ is differentiable in $z_0 \in G$. Thus if first partial derivatives of $u$ and $v$ are continuous and satisfy C-R-equations $\forall z\in G$, then $f$ is analytic in $G$. So you would not need (real) differentiability of $u$ and $v$ as precondition for analyticity of $f$[Kompleksianalyysi1a.pdf, 23].